# Issue with @string and developing for android

Tags: android, string

I am trying to write a sms receiver for android.  But I am having issues.  I found an example here: http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android

Eclipse had underlined the line : 
    android:text="Update SMS list" />

So I changed it to:

```
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_margin="2dip"
    android:text="@string/UpdateList"
    android:id="@+id/UpdateList"/>
```

and added this into strings.xml :

```
<string name="UpdateList">Update SMS List</string>
```

The issue is now with the line :

```
android:text="@string/UpdateList"
```

This is the error message:

[2013-03-14 16:37:07 - FindMyPhone] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Does anyone see what the issue is?  Or have an idea of how to fix it?

Comment: that issue is show when you open the activity from thephone, always close the app before lauch from the IDE

Comment: What kind of issue do you have?

Comment: The string substitution and the "error" message (which is a warning) are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Underline Issue:**
I reckon the Linter just hasn't noticed the change yet, I often find that saving the file, closing it and opening it up again, is required to clear it's "cache", if it can be called that, of errors / warnings.

> ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has
>   been brought to the front

This just means that the Activity is open on the device/emulator and you're launching it again. This happens if the code hasn't changed since the last launch, and it brings the current Activity to the front.

Answer (score 0):

```
[2013-03-14 16:37:07 - FindMyPhone] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

This generally indicates that the APK being installed on the device isn't different from what is on there already.  Based on your question, the error can be resolved by cleaning and rebuilding the application, then reloading it on to your device.

Answer (score 0):

> [2013-03-14 16:37:07 - FindMyPhone] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Your code isn't the problem, it's that the app is currently running on the emulator/device and Eclipse is trying to launch it again. Just hit back until you get to the home screen and try to launch it again.